# Azure APIM calls function even though there was an error

Tags: azure-api-management

I have an Azure APIM which checks the request bearer JWT token:

```
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="TenantId" value="
            @{
                var tenantId = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("TenantId","");
         
                    if (tenantId != null) {
                        return tenantId;
                    }
                 
            return null;
    }" />
        <limit-concurrency key="@((string)context.Variables["TenantId"])" max-count="1">
            <set-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="delete" />
            <set-header name="subscription-key" exists-action="delete" />
            <set-variable name="JWTIssuer" value="
    @{
        var authStr = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","");
        if (authStr.StartsWith("Bearer")) {
            var jwt = authStr.Substring("Bearer ".Length).AsJwt();
            if (jwt != null) {
                return jwt.Issuer;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }" />
            
            <choose>
                <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("JWTIssuer", "") == "<URL of issuer>")">
                    <!-- Authorisation using HPCA token -->
                    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
                        <openid-config url="<Open Id Url>" />
                        <required-claims>
                            <claim name="MyClaim" match="any" separator=",">
                                <value>X</value>
                            </claim>
                        </required-claims>
                    </validate-jwt>
                </when>
                <!-- HPCA Error handling -->
                <otherwise>
                    <return-response>
                        <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized" />
                        <set-header name="WWW-Authenticate" exists-action="override">
                            <value>Bearer error "Invalid HPCA token"</value>
                        </set-header>
                    </return-response>
                </otherwise>
            </choose>            
        </limit-concurrency>
    </inbound>
<on-error>
        <base />
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="@(context.Response.StatusCode)" reason="@(context.Response.StatusReason)" />
        </return-response>
    </on-error>
```

This all works as expected: if either the issuer is incorrect or the JWT token is invalid, then the  OnError handler is invoked and a 401 error status is returned to the caller. The problem is, if i add a call to a function after the Choose policy:

```
     </otherwise>
                </choose>    
    <send-request mode="copy" response-variable-name="Response" timeout="10" ignore-error="false">
                    <set-url>https://myfuncApp.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1</set-url>
                    <set-method>POST</set-method>
                    
                </send-request>
                <return-response response-variable-name="Response">
                    <set-status code="@(context.Response.StatusCode)" reason="@(context.Response.StatusReason)" />
                </return-response>
</limit-concurrency>
</inbound>
```

Then even with a invalid bearer token and the error handler being invoked, the APIM *still* proceeds to call the function: the return response within the error handler is seemingly ignored - why ? I can fudge it by wrapping the send-request within another conditional (i.e. check the context.Response.StatusCode isn't 401) but this doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: The best way to investigate this would be to make a test call from Azure Portal and take a look at trace available there. You could post it here as well, but be weary of secrets it exposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question, I think the result of your test is normal.

You added the `<send-request>` to request the function in `<inbound>` area. The `<validate-jwt>` can just determine if the APIM to continue request the backend url but can not determine if it continues to request function url in `<inbound>` area.